# which sparse matrix for scipys linprog algorithms?

Tags: numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, scipy-optimize

I want to solve a big LP problem with sciPy's linprog solvers but I'm  getting memory errors.
I had them from numpy during the formulation of my LP and in the solver itself.

Does anyone know if there's a way to pass sciPy linprog solvers sparse matrices?
I guess using sparse matrices instead of normal numpy matrices would also solve the memory errors from numpy

I've checked the documentation
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html

but it doesnt really say what type of sparse matrix is accepted as input?

Comment: While "sparse" is used several times in the docs, I doubt if it's referring to a scipy.sparse matrix.  scikit-learn functions that accept `sparse` are more explicit about that.  `csr` format is used for all linear-algebra calculations, since it is the one that implements matrix-multiplication.  But does `linprog` use that or a matrix inverse?

Comment: A quick glimpse at the code (e.g. [this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/701ffcc8a6f04509d115aac5e5681c538b5265a2/scipy/optimize/_linprog_util.py#L120)) makes me believe, that you can use scipy.sparse mats as `A_eq` and `A_ub`. If that would not be possible, the solver would be just a toy-solver (imho). There are also some indications in the docs, do a text-search for: `For problems with sparse input, this option is ignored, and the pivot-based algorithm presented in [5] is used`.  Make sure to use one of the "non-toy" solvers though (i expect highs-ds to be the most *sparse*).

Comment: Addition: In any good implementation, sparse is sparse on API-lvl. It doesn't (really) matter if you put csr/csc/dok/coo there as internally things will be transformed anyways (with O(nonzeros) work). None of the Simplex-based solvers work on scipy.sparse matrices anyway. IPMs might do, but they make sure, that the type is prepared as needed.